# Linq to SQL getting child elements

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have four tables in my database. Now, I would like to build an object to use on my client side. Everything worked well for a special language, only the translations of my fields fail.

```
Parent Table:
ConfigTable

Child Table 1:
TestTranslations --> ConfigTableId Foreign Key
Child Table 2:
TestTableFields --> ConfigTableId Foreign Key

Child Table of Table 2:
TestTableFieldsTranslations --> TestTableFieldId Foreign Key
```

And here is my try...

```
var dbquery = from bdCon in this.GetAll()
            select new
            {
                bdCon,
                translations = from trans in bdCon.TestTranslations
                               where trans.LanguageID == languageId
                    select trans,
                fields = from fields in bdCon.TestTableFields where bdCon.Id == fields.ConfigTableId 
                         join fieldTrans in  this.Context.TestTableFieldsTranslations
                         on fields.Id equals fieldTrans.TestTableFieldId
             where fieldTrans.LanguageID == languageId
                         select fields
            };

        var query = dbquery
           .AsEnumerable() 
           .Select(m => m.bdCon);
        return query;
```

Comment: What do you mean with `translations of my fields fail`? In last query you you select only `dbCon` and omit other properties, so `translations` and `fields` is never returned from your query. Is it ok for you?

Comment: My object looks like: I get an array of all configtables and all translations of the table and all fields which belong to the table but the fields also have translations. I would like to get these translations too.

Comment: A qualifier! "This" is redundant here